# client.commands empty on interactionCreateEvent

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Heyho

I've been coding a new private discord bot using discord.js in the past days.
When running it, at first, it seemed to work:

- it logged in perfectly
- commands were registered and showed up when typing "/" in discord
- the bot showed up in my member list

HOWEVER: when trying to execute a command that I had copied from another one of my projects - so I knew that it would not have any issues - I encountered an error saying that `client.commands` was empty:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Object.execute (..\moderationbot\src\events\general\interactionCreate.js:14:41)
    at Client.<anonymous> (..\moderationbot\src\deployEvents.js:22:58)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (..\moderationbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (..\moderationbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (..\moderationbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (..\moderationbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:494:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (..\moderationbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (..\moderationbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (..\moderationbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

As I had defined the client before in my `index.js`, set `client.commands` in `deployCommands.js` and imported it into `interactionCreate.js`, I was wondering why it was empty now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

It turned out that `client.commands` was not set globally in the client, just inside the interactionCreate event. Hence I had to import the client used in `index.js` into `deployCommands.js` and then import the client used in `deployCommands.js` into `interactionCreate.js`.
So here's how I did it:

### index.js:

```
require("dotenv");

const client = new Client({
    partials: partials,
    intents: intents
});

//other code
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN).then(r => console.log("Logged in as " + client.user.tag));

module.exports = {
    client
};
```

### deployCommands.js:

```
const client = require("./index.js");
client.commands = new Collection()
    
async function run() {
    
    //other code
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    
}

module.exports = {
    client
}
```

### interactionCreate.js

```
const client  = require('./../../index.js').client;
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    once: false,

    async execute(interaction) {

        //other code   
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        try {

            await command.execute(interaction);

        } catch (error)
            //other code

    },
};
```

Don't know if it was that obvious and I am just stupid, but I cloudn't find anything on the internet - even after googling for hours. I'm glad I figured it out myself now and I am hoping I can save someone some time of despair when trying to solve the issue :)

("other code" refers mostly to the tutorial on [Discord JS Guide](https://discordjs.guide/))